# How can I animate a linked character and save the animations to the original file?

Tags: animation, linked-data

I have two rigged characters, each with their own file with a rig and deforming mesh.

I’m trying to animate these characters to dance with each other, which means it will be much easier to animate with them in the same project so they can coordinate their movements, so I created a third file that I linked both characters into and made a library override for both.

However, I would like the animation data I create for each character to apply separately to both characters, so when I bring them into a game engine, they can operate as individual characters who will join together to dance. However, to my understanding, it’s not possible to save animation data back to a linked file automatically- the new animations are only saved in the local file.

Is the easiest way to do this just to manually copy-paste the animation from the overrides back to the original files, or is there a way for the animations to dynamically apply to their respective files as I work?

Comment: In the *Action Editor* you should find the animation that you have created. Make sure you click the shield icon ("fake user") to protect it. This is important when you create more than one and they are not assigned to the character but you want to save them. Then save the file and open the original file of the character. There you can import the action with the main menu entry File > Append... Choose the actions(s) to copy them.